# First lesson in TestFirst Ruby Course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to complete the TestFirst.org learn_ruby course, and I'm stuck right at the beginning of the first one.

I open a terminal window at the directory `00_hello`, just like the instructions say. But then when I go to run the first test "rake" (which is supposed to fail several times before it passes) I'm getting a weird error message that I can't seem to track down.

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:00_hello TheRedFool$ rake
(in /Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master)
rake aborted!
undefined method `gem' for main:Object
/Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master/Rakefile:2
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Then when I run it with the trace.

```
Michaels-MacBook-Pro:00_hello TheRedFool$ rake --trace
(in /Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master)
rake aborted!
undefined method `gem' for main:Object
/Users/TheRedFool/learn_ruby-master/Rakefile:2
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/bin/rake:31
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the rakefile look like?

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work using rspec instead of rake. I got through the first lesson just fine this way.

```
jrw@mobile0:~/.../00_hello$ rspec -r hello_spec.rb
```

I think rake isn't recognizing RubyGems, but I'm not sure why.  I'm using Ubuntu, so [Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846804/whats-the-deal-with-rubygems-on-debian-its-different-and-strange) may have something to do with it.  At any rate, rspec should be a sufficient substitute until rake gets fixed.

**EDIT:**

I  figured out the real problem. Navigate to the main Test First Ruby folder and open `Rakefile` in a text editor. Add this line before the one that says `gem 'rspec', '~>2'`:

```
require 'rubygems'
```

This line isn't necessary in Ruby 1.9.1, but you and I are running 1.8.

If for some reason that still doesn't work for you, you can use this command in the exercise folders, and it should do EXACTLY the same thing as typing `rake`, but without the error:

```
jrw@mobile0:~/.../00_hello$ rspec -I. -f d -r ../rspec_config *_spec.rb
```

Comment: If you get this error: `Could not find rspec (~> 2) amongst [...]`, then you also need to install the rspec gem: `$ gem install rspec`

Comment: Also, if you've created the file for the test (`hello.rb`) and still get a LoadError (`cannot load such file -- hello`), you might have spaces in the directory path. Open `Rakefile` again and add `.gsub(' ', '\ ')` to the end of the line that says `lab = Rake.application.original_dir`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like gem is out of date on your system. Try:

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. Ok I just tried updating it, but now I'm getting an error message 

Michaels-MacBook-Pro:00_hello TheRedFool$ gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.


Any idea how I can get around that? Thanks.

Comment: Also just tried the update outside of the 00_hello directory, and got the same error. Not sure what the heck is going on.

Comment: do sudo before the command. you need to be root to update gem

Comment: Ok just did that, and the gems updated fine. But I'm still getting an error message. Maybe my syntax for running the rake test is off? What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: can you please add the output of 'rspec -v' to make sure you have rspec installed correctly?

Comment: Turns out it was a complete noob problem, where I didn't understand that I actually didn't have rspec installed. I went through and did that, now things are working. Thanks for the help @bootstraps.